# Change stylesheet depend on time in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I need to change stylesheets depend on time of the day, for example:

`if current_time > 6pm { use stylesheet 1} else { stylesheet 2 }`

I do this with jQuery:

```
function getStylesheet() {
  var currentTime = new Date().getHours();
  if (7 >= currentTime&&currentTime > 18) {
   $('head').append("<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/day.css' type='text/css'>");
  }
  else {
   $('head').append("<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/night.css' type='text/css'>");
  }
}

getStylesheet();
```

How I can do the same on Wordpress?

I look at codex, I can use current_time,

```
$time = current_time( 'timestamp', 1  );
```

but how I make it like:

```
$night = "return 6pm here"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this on where you register your stylesheet.

```
if ( current_time('H') >= 7 && current_time('H') < 18) {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'time-stylesheet', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/day.css', array(), null );
} else {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'time-stylesheet', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/night.css', array(), null );
}
```

> **NOTE:** `current_time()` it returns the current time of the
>   site/blog not the user/visitor time. So make your you set your blog/site timezone to UTC.

Not tested so, let me know. What's happen.

Comment: work like a charm, thanks for the solution. But actually I just need to know how to specify hours :)

Comment: sorry i didn't get you

Comment: Add multiple if statements like mlbd shows in his answer.. he defined hours between 7 and 18

Answer (score 1):

You can also use js for time detection based on the client which is more appropriate.. best code source for doing so https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/different-stylesheet-pending-the-time-of-day/ place that snippet in your theme js file or directly in your themes header.php

Comment: sorry, that's not what I looking for. I have my stylesheet enqueued in functions.php and also link like `<link rel='stylesheet' href='night.css' type='text/css'>' won't work at wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

You can alternatively use `'style_loader_src'` filter too, to filter stiles with condition, or change return string, with desired style, example:

```
add_filter( 'style_loader_src', function($href){
if(strpos($href, "name-of-allowed.css") !== false) {
return $href;
}
return false;
});
```